# Failing to get videos from Youtube feeds

Tags: javascript, youtube, feed

I am using the following code to access youtube feed .Is this the correct code? I am not getting the video. though the swf is show on the screen

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function youtube()
  {
     var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always", bgcolor: "#cccccc" };
     var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };

     swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/results?border=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=ytplayer","ytapiplayer", "300", "250", "8",null, null, params, atts);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You should not HTML encode the URL. Replace `&amp;` with a simple `&`.